# Call procedure from different schema which has ACL privilege but caller doesn't

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, acl

One schema in our database has ACL privilege to an URL and can send requests to this URL. If I now write a procedure in this schema that sends the request and grants a **different** schema the option to execute this procedure, will it work or does the second schema also need the ACL privilege?

I am asking to plan the necessary approach to this topic since I need to write an package in the second schema.

Comment: Do not ask if it will work, write a small test case. If it fails then post that along with the error. If it works then you have your answer. The community would ask you to post what you tried anyway.

Comment: Alright thank you. Yes this what I have done now anyway now but I will remember it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly it seems like that by default the authid property is set to **definer rights**. This should mean that it executes with the privileges of the owner of the schema.

And it indeed did!

Refrence:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG658
2. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_package.htm#LNPLS01371
3. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809